# The numbers in `<ol>` cover a `<div>` which is floating to the left. How do I move those numbers to the right, so that they don't cover it?

Tags: html, css

If you open [this blog-post of mine](https://flatassembler.github.io/toponyms.html), on higher resolutions, you can see that the numbers of the `<ol>` element cover the `<div>` with a picture and caption that is floating to the right:
[image: Screenshot of my Croatian Toponyms page]
How do I move the numbers of the `<ol>` to the right so that they don't cover the `<div>`?
Here is (I think) minimal reproducible example:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Numbers of the "ol" element covering a div</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background: #777777; float: left;"></div>
<ol>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</li>
</ol>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is what it looks like in Firefox:
[image: The screenshot of the minimal reproducible example]
So, what should I add to the CSS of the `<ol>` to make sure its numbers do not cover the `<div>` under any resolution?

Comment: You could set the `ol` style to: `style='display:inline-block;'`